# WINAPI INetCfg interface returning undocumented error code on subsequent initialisations

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I'm working with the Windows API [INetCfg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547694(v=vs.85)) interface and I've come across an issue when [initialising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547977(v=vs.85)) the net config instance that I receive a handle to, but never on the initial pass, only on subsequent passes. What I see when I call netCfg->Initialize(NULL) is a return value of -2147416372 which essentially translates to 0x800106CC. I've looked the code up [here](https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=hresult&code=800106CC) and found that it is an RPC error and it in fact specifically corresponds to the error RPC_S_DUPLICATE_ENDPOINT (thanks to [@SimonMourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) for this information). This is not a documented return code for Initialize. The documentation states:

> Returns zero (S_OK) if successful; otherwise, returns NETCFG_* codes that are defined in Netcfgx.h.

Interestingly, I seem to be able to work around this issue by re-attempting to initialise. I seem to consistently get an S_OK return code on the second attempt and can continue to successfully use the netcfg interface to perform the actions I need to after this.

In my app I am using a simple custom wrapper (NetworkConfiguration) that performs all the required setup of the INetCfg interface in its constructor and all the required teardown in the destructor. The network configuration is performed on a worker thread with a CoInitializeEx call at the start and a CoUninitialize call at the end. All calls to COM interfaces are performed between the CoInitializeEx and CoUninitialize calls. Network configuration is never performed on more than one thread at a time. The complete configuration is processed and applied once in its entirety every time an updated configuration is received and COM objects are never shared between threads. You can actually completely remove multithreading from the equation in the below example and still experience the same issue, but I wanted to make my simulated setup as close to my real setup as possible.

Here is the complete code listing that simulates my setup and fully reproduces the issue I've been seeing:

```
#include <netcfgx.h> // For INetCfg and related interfaces

#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

class NetworkConfiguration
{
public:
    NetworkConfiguration() : pNetCfg(NULL), pNetCfgLock(NULL)
    {
        const auto createInstanceRc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CNetCfg, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_INetCfg, (LPVOID*)&pNetCfg);
        if (createInstanceRc != S_OK)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::format("CoCreateInstance error: {}", createInstanceRc));
        }

        const auto queryInterfaceRc = pNetCfg->QueryInterface(IID_INetCfgLock, (LPVOID*)&pNetCfgLock);
        if (queryInterfaceRc != S_OK)
        {
            pNetCfg->Release();

            throw std::runtime_error(std::format("QueryInterface error: {}", queryInterfaceRc));
        }

        LPWSTR szwrClient = NULL;
        const auto acquireLockRc = pNetCfgLock->AcquireWriteLock(5000, L"MyApp", &szwrClient);
        if (acquireLockRc != S_OK)
        {
            pNetCfg->Release();

            throw std::runtime_error(std::format("AcquireWriteLock error: {}", acquireLockRc));
        }

        // With reattempts
        constexpr auto ErrorMask = (1 << 16) - 1;
        HRESULT initNetCfgRc = S_FALSE;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            initNetCfgRc = pNetCfg->Initialize(NULL);
            if (initNetCfgRc == S_OK)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Try to re-initialise. Once we've flushed this state that seems to be OK
            if ((initNetCfgRc & ErrorMask) != RPC_S_DUPLICATE_ENDPOINT)
            {
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "Encountered duplicate endpoint. Continuing...\n";
        }

        // Without reattempts - Comment above and uncomment this to experience the error
        // const auto initNetCfgRc = pNetCfg->Initialize(NULL);

        if (initNetCfgRc != S_OK)
        {
            pNetCfgLock->ReleaseWriteLock();
            pNetCfg->Release();

            throw std::runtime_error(std::format("Initialise error: {}", initNetCfgRc));
        }
    }

    ~NetworkConfiguration()
    {
        const auto applyRc = pNetCfg->Apply();
        if (applyRc != S_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Error applying network configuration. Error code: " << applyRc << "\n";
        }

        const auto uninitialiseRc = pNetCfg->Uninitialize();
        if (uninitialiseRc != S_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Error uninitialising network configuration interface. Error code: " << uninitialiseRc << "\n";
        }

        const auto releaseLockRc = pNetCfgLock->ReleaseWriteLock();
        if (releaseLockRc != S_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Error releasing write lock. Error code: " << releaseLockRc << "\n";
        }

        pNetCfg->Release();
    }

private:
    INetCfg* pNetCfg;
    INetCfgLock* pNetCfgLock;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, []() -> int {
            int rc = 0;
            try
            {
                const auto initRc = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
                if (initRc != S_OK)
                {
                    const auto err = std::format("CoInitialise error: {}", initRc);
                    CoUninitialize();
                    throw std::runtime_error(err);
                }

                {
                    NetworkConfiguration configuration;
                    // Network configuration performed here in the real app
                }

                CoUninitialize();
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
                rc = -1;
            }
            return rc;
            });

        fut.wait();
        std::cout << "Round " << i + 1 << " return code: " << fut.get() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I'm working in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10

My questions are:

1. Why does the Initialize function on the INetCfg interface return an undocumented RPC error code?
2. What is the API user expected to do with this return code if it is undocumented?
3. Why is it that when I seemingly flush this error state and attempt a reinitialisation that I can then use the INetCfg interface with no problems?

Any insight would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: *"What is the API user expected to do with this return code if it is undocumented?"* - The ordinary: Pass it into the `SUCCEEDED()` or `FAILED()` macros to determine the outcome. API documentation rarely (if ever) lists the full set of error values any given API can return.

Comment: You shouldn't lie about how you found the initial error meaning and continue on your original question instead of creating a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801218/windows-api-inetcfg-interface-failing-to-initialise-with-undocumented-return-cod

Comment: @SimonMourier My apologies. It was never my intention to lie about the source of the error message meaning - I will edit the question to credit you and thank you for helping me with this. I decided to remove the old question as it wasn't well received and I thought it would be more helpful to start with a clean slate and a new discussion about the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your feedback. In the general case this makes sense, what I don't understand though is that I seem to be able to recover from the particular error that I get. I suppose this would make sense if it is common when working with COM objects to retry when you get a failure return code regardless of what it is, though I'm inexperienced with COM and not sure if this is the case.

Comment: I think my instinct after finding that retrying worked was that in certain cases if Initialize fails you are in a position to try again and in other cases you may not be e.g. in the case of a resource not initially being available vs an init error. It seems intuitive to me that there would be different error codes to indicate these cases